# Spring mvc - redirect not work properly

Tags: ajax, spring, spring-mvc

I have a page with registration form. User can click submit button, which cause post request to my server.

My controller looks like this :

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/register", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String registerUser(@RequestBody UserDTO userDTO) {
    userService.addUser(userDTO);
    return "redirect:/login";
}
```

but the problem is that redirect isn't working properly. In firebug or chrome tools I can see this get request to /login page, but my browser doesn't update.

I am making post request via ajax

Comment: add your spring web context files(<servlet-name>-servlet.xm) and web.xml file in your question

Comment: Judging from your method you are using JavaScript to post (you are posting JSON). Instead of your page there is another means that gets the redirect and that is already handled but not with your current page but in the background. Return an HTTP status and if you get a OK (HTTP 200) then redirect in your javascript code, else show the same page with an error.